# Illustrator scripting for text baseline (javascript)

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a script for illustrator but my code seems to not be working and doing nothing on me.
It's supposed to make the "(" and ")" characters baselines to be 3px.
Looking for someone who can make this work.

```js
  function test(){
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var t = doc.textFrames[0], thisChar, thisSize, thisBaseline;
    for(var i=0; i<t.characters.length; i++){
      thisChar = t.characters;
      if(thisChar.contents == "(" || thisChar.contents == ")"){
        thisSize =  thisChar.characterAttributes.size;
        thisBaseline = thisChar.characterAttributes.baselineShift;
        thisChar.characterAttributes.baselineShift = 3;
      }
    };
  };
  test();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var frames = app.activeDocument.selection;

for (var j=0; j<frames.length; j++) {
    if (frames[j].typename == "TextFrame") {
        for (var i=0; i<frames[j].characters.length; i++) {
            var ch = frames[j].characters[i];
            if( ch.contents == "(" || ch.contents == ")" ) ch.baselineShift = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

It shifts baseline for all brackets within all selected objects.

*Note*: this simple implementation doesn't handle grouped objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
var frames = app.activeDocument.textFrames;

for (var j=0; j<frames.length; j++) {
    for (var i=0; i<frames[j].characters.length; i++) {
        var ch = frames[j].characters[i];
        if( ch.contents == "(" || ch.contents == ")" ) ch.baselineShift = 3;
    }
}
```

This variant of the script does the work within all text frames (grouped or not). You don't have to select anything.

Comment: While it's possible to give multiple answers per question (this answer and [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111167/5698098)), please give a single answer per question. If you have multiple solution variants then include and discuss them in one answer. See the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for possibilities on how to structre such an answer; possibly you want to use headings or a horizontal rule to separate your variants.